# CAShapeLayer offsetting from UIVIew's CALayer

Tags: uiview

I'm trying to add a CAShapeLayer to a custom UIViews layer, which is going well, except for the fact that it's offsetting itself...

It's probably best I explain with code and screenshots.. So here it goes:

All I'm trying to achieve is a simple "slash" like CAShapeLayer in Swift 3.

in the custom UIView I have:

```
    var slashLayer: CAShapeLayer?
var slashPath: CGPath?

override func layoutSublayers(of layer: CALayer) {
    if layer == self.layer {
        if slashLayer == nil {
            slashLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            slashLayer?.bounds = layer.bounds
            slashLayer?.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            slashLayer?.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            slashLayer?.lineWidth = 3.0

            let slashPath = UIBezierPath()
            slashPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: layer.frame.minX, y: layer.frame.minY))
            slashPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: layer.frame.maxX, y: layer.frame.maxY))
            slashPath.close()

            slashLayer?.path = slashPath.cgPath

            layer.addSublayer(slashLayer!)
        }
    }
}
```

And that's it in the UIView subclass.

This is what I wind up with in Interface Builder (and the App when I fire it up)..

As CALayer.layoutManager isn't around any more, how do I keep the layers in  line with one-another?

[image: Screenshot of the Custom UIView in Interface Builder - Shot 1]
[image: Screenshot of the Custom UIView in Interface Builder - Shot 2]

Answer (score 0):

You should use `layer.bounds` instead of `layer.frame`, as `layer.frame` in your case represents the position+size of your custom UIView in its superview's coordinate system. However, your CAShapeLayer sublayer lives within your custom UIView's coordinate system.

```
slashPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: layer.bounds.minX, y: layer.bounds.minY))
slashPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: layer.bounds.maxX, y: layer.bounds.maxY))
```